# MYSQLI not putting data into the database

Tags: php

```
<?php 

    $data = array(

    0 => 'Natural Chlid 1',
    1 => 'Natural Chlid 2',
    2 => 'Natural Chlid 3'
    ); 
    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'mutli_page_form');

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    $serialized = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, serialize($data));

    $result = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO wills_children ('will', 'children') VALUES (123, '$serialized')");

    if (!$result) {
        printf("Error message: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
    }

?>
```

this doesn't seem to send the data to the database the error im getting is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''will', 'children') VALUES (123, 'a:3:{i:0;s:15:\"Natural Chlid 1\";i:1;s:15:\"N' at line 1
```

Comment: Put $link inside mysqli_error();

Comment: www.php.net/mysqli_error tells you that you need to give the function link identifier, which you haven't done. Use mysqli_error($link) to see what mysql complains about.

Comment: i have done that and now i have the "actual" error in the above post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
if (!$result) {
    printf("Error message: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
}
```

to see the error message.

Edit:

Try this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO wills_children (will, children) VALUES (123, '$serialized')");
```

Comment: thx i have changed the code and now a new error has popped up.

Comment: Winner, Winner, Chicken Dinner !

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli_error` expect at least one parameter that is link to database.

Pass that parameter and problem will be solved

```
mysqli_error($link);
```

Do not put the quotes arround the column name instead you can use backquote to avoid reserved word error.

```
(`will`, `children`)
```

Comment: thanks i have changed that and now a new error has popped up !